# What did Ehud Olmert mean by these statements on a two state solution for Israel?

Tags: israel, palestine, apartheid

In the book of essays edited by Akeel Bilgrami which explores the notion of academic freedom, and is titled *Who's Afraid of Academic Freedom*, John Meirshiemer in the essay *Israel and Academic Freedom* writes the following:

> Greater Israel will be an apartheid state. Former Israeli prime minister Ehud Olmert made this point in November 2007, when he said that if there was no two-state solution, Israel will face a "South African style struggle". He went so far as to argue that "as soon as that happens, the state of Israel is finished".

What's surprising here, given how often Palestinians are accused of wanting to deny the existence of the state of Israel, is that a former prime minister of Israel is making this claim; and this claim is not isolated for he goes on to write:

> Former Prime minister Ehud Barak, who later became Israels defense minister said in February 2010 that
>
> "as long as the territory west of the Jordan river there is only one political entity called Israel is going to be either non-Jewish or non-democratic. If this bloc of millions of Palestinians cannot vote, that will be an apartheid state".

My questions are the following:

1. What did Ehud Barak mean by saying "this bloc of Palestinians cannot vote"? Was this the case in 2010, and if not, then why did he say such a thing, and is it still the case in 2017?
2. What did Ehud Olmert mean by saying "the state of Israel is finished"? In what way would he have envisaged the state of Israel finishing? For example, we see that in South Africa the system of apartheid was dismantled, yet there still remains a state called South Africa.

Comment: Got a link to the essay? I have a feeling there's some context missing

Comment: @Machavity: I'm afraid not, no; it's an essay in a book, it's actually called *Who's Afraid of Academic Freedom*, you're welcome to look up the essay there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can not read minds. An answer like the one by Machavity which tries to reason from the circumstances is the closest we could get.

Comment: @Philipp - it's not reaing minds at all. He was referring to very specific set of facts.

Comment: @philipp: its not a matter of reading minds, but a matter of reading the essay in question...

Comment: @Philipp - to be more specific, it's a matter of reading (or having read) other discussions on this exact topic including from same figures, and knowing what facts they cited on the topic outside that essay .

Comment: @brythan: it covers some similar territory but the question is very different, in particular the emphasis on aparthied by both senior Israeli political figures, and also the question on voting rights.

Comment: @brythan: as I don't consider the possible duplicate an actual duplicate how do I edit it out?

Comment: In general:  acknowledge what you learned from the answers to the previous question; explain what you still don't understand; narrow the question down to just what you don't understand.  In this particular case, perhaps "Was Israel an apartheid state where the Palestinians couldn't vote?  In 2010?  Now?"  And leave the second question for the future.

Answer (score 6):

The earlier answer by Machavity pretty much nails the general idea on the head but lacks specific #s:

> Jews in Israel: 6,119K (growth rate 1.7%)
>   Arabs in Israel: 1,688K (growth rate 2.1%)
>   [Palestinians in PA+Gaza+East jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_Palestinian_territories#Vital_statistics): 2,569+192,800+1,657=4,419K (growth rate ~3%)
>   Total Palestinians: 6,107K

**So, there's as many Jews as Arabs NOW. If you consider birth rates, the Jews will be a minority, and more and more so, as time goes on**.

This is confirmed by [Haaretz quoting Palestinian Central Bureau of Statics (PCBS)](http://forward.com/news/breaking-news/328404/palestinian-population-to-pass-jews-by-2017-in-israel-and-territories/):

> **The number of Palestinians in Israel and the occupied territories will equal the number of Jews by the end of 2017, according to a report issued by the Palestinian Central Bureau of Statics (PCBS.)**
>
> The number of Palestinians worldwide is currently estimated at 12.37 million, with 4.75 million living in the Gaza Strip and the West Bank (1.85 million and 2.9 million respectively,) 1.47 million in Israel, 5.46 million in Arab countries and some 685,000 in non-Arab countries

---

This means one of two things for one-state solution:

1. Option 1: "Democratic state". Most importantly, that means Palestinian Arabs have voting rights, **same as Israeli Arabs have today**.

   Except, unlike in 2017 Israel, in one-state solution, Palestinians are in permanent majority. Jews are at best at permanent minority.

   This is further exacerbated by the fact that there's a reasonably big fraction of left wing Jews who would vote the same way as Palestinians on many issues, such as Meretz and their ilk; making Palestinian majority effectively even larger.

   - Best (imho, less likely) case scenario, it's not a Jewish state because Palestinians vote for it not to be so (as in, any "Jewish specialness" disappears).

     Note that [Palestinians don't even support Jewish nature of Israel *in the context of two-state solution*](http://www.pcpsr.org/en/node/625), never mind one-state one:

     > Similarly, only 39% support a mutual recognition of national identity of Israel as the state for the Jewish people and Palestine as the state for the Palestinian people and 61% oppose it.
   - Worse case scenario (extremely realistic): the first law passed is Palestinian right of return, meaning potentially up to another 5.4 to 6 Million Palestinians come from outside world to live in this one state, making Palestinian majority even larger.
   - Worst case scenario: permanent Palestinian majority votes to implement [what most Palestinians want **according to 2014 Washington Institute for Middle East policy poll**](http://www.washingtoninstitute.org/policy-analysis/view/new-palestinian-poll-shows-hardline-views-but-some-pragmatism-too) (throw Jews back into the sea)

     > ... now, **a clear majority (60% overall, including 55% in the West Bank and 68% in Gaza) say that the five-year goal "should be to work toward reclaiming all of historic Palestine, from the river to the sea."** ...
     >
     > This pattern is confirmed by other questions in the survey. **For example, just one-third said that a two-state solution "should be the end of the conflict." Nearly two-thirds said "resistance should continue until all of historic Palestine is liberated."**

     A separate [Watan research center poll from 2015](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/204071#.VlxyPXarTIV):
2. Option 2: A state where Palestinians (who are majority) can't vote.

   That can realistically be considered similar situation to South African Apartheid, even though SA Apartheid included radical amount of oppression that's lacking in Israel (today, while some actual effective discrimination does occur (see Or report), [officially Israeli Arabs have virtually same legal rights as Israeli Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_citizens_of_Israel#Legal_and_political_status), according to all laws including Israeli Declaration of Independence).

Comment: It seems like you intended to quote from the Watan research centrer poll, but didn't. Also, your link is to Arutz7, which is strongly biased. A link to Watan research or an objective analysis would be better.

Comment: Your discussion of option 2 mixes this hypothetical one state, with millions of citizens who can't vote, with today's Israel, where Arab citizens have equal rights. This hypothetical state would be a big step towards SA Apartheid, at least in this aspect.

Comment: @ugoren - I kind of hoped it would be clear which is which with "oppression that's lacking in Israel (**today**" wording. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Your use of "even though" indicates that the lacking oppression in today's Israel somehow contradicts considering the hypothetical Israel as Apartheid.

Comment: @ugoren - hm. Wasn't what I was trying to express. I was just trying to preempt "Israel is apartheid already" BS responses

Answer (score 3):

There are about [6.1 million Jews in Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Israel) (with about 2 million non-Jews), about [3.7 million in the Palestinian territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_Palestinian_territories). For argument's sake, let's assume a one state solution with Jews and non-Jews as the major political division (so 5.7 million on the other end).

In a one state solution, you now have voting along racial/religious lines. So that means a Jewish state running basically the whole thing. That's not terribly dissimilar to how it is now, but Gaza and the West Bank [have their own elected governments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_National_Authority) (although very few outside governments recognize them). But with a one state solution, Palestinians would now officially be under the Jewish government. That limits any outside influence. Given a permanent minority status, apartheid would probably become the de-facto normal, as the Jewish government would (for security reasons) continue to limit and contain Palestinians, who would likely continue to engage in terrorist acts. Their elected representatives would protest, but not gain any traction in light of the fact that some of their constituents would be actively seeking to undermine the government.

And this is the best-case scenario.

The worst-case would see Palestinians denied the right to vote. A terrorist act against polling places by Hamas, whose [charter states](http://www.latimes.com/world/la-fg-hamas-charter-20170501-story.html)

> complete liberation of Palestine from the river to the sea.

would be likely, since an open democratic election would ensure the legitimacy of the newly elected government (which is against Hamas' stated goals). Israeli forces would close some, if not all, Palestinian polling places (not hard to imagine given the [recent limiting of Palestinian access to the Temple Mount in Jerusalem](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Politics-And-Diplomacy/Israel-removes-Temple-Mount-metal-detectors-that-enraged-the-Muslim-world-500663)). So the Jewish population would win a lopsided victory, but without the legitimacy of a full and free election (but arguably not because of their actions). So some governments would not recognize them, while others would note the attempt. This would be an even more ripe environment for apartheid, just with a (somewhat) legitimate government running it.

Comment: Interesting analysis; however it doesn't really explain the comments made by either Ehud Olmert or Ehud Barak, apart from ratifying  that aparthied is a suitable lense to view the situation.

Comment: In fact, that was a worry of mine, as aparthied in the South African context is ostensibly about race, whereas in the situation referred to this seems less so, after all both Hebrew and Arabic are called Semitic languages.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - that's just a colloquialism. Using the word in terms of "oppression" in general as opposed to "race based oppression".

Comment: @user4012: what is a "colloquialism"?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Unlike South Africa, I don't think Israel *wants* apartheid. Instead, you would have a sort of "reverse" apartheid, where one side forces the other to oppress it, since it helps their political goals (Hamas in particular seems to prefer mass Palestinian casualties to peace, and for that reason they could never run Israel). Sorry if that wasn't clear. As to `colloquialism`, he's using this term for lack of a better one. Sometimes you have to use the next closest term so people understand what you mean

Comment: @machavity: I'm not sure that clarifies anything, in what way are the Palestinians responsible for the oppression of Israel when in all responsible accounts I've looked at, Israeli militias had ethnically cleansed Palestine, leading to the current impasse on the West Bank and Gaza? Anyway, none of this is actually tackling the substance of my question, ie the voting rights of Palestinians; I still don't understand what he meant by colloquialism, it seems you have a better grasp of it, care to explain further? It seems to be a term that's been bandied around in a few places...

Comment: @MoziburUllah A colloquialism is using a common word or phrase in a way that doesn't necessarily mean everything the original word meant. So, in this case, apartheid was a deliberate attempt to segregate races in South Africa. Israel has something very similar to apartheid now, but there's a legitimate case to be made that terrorism is necessitating some of it. Olmert was using the term apartheid (which carries a deeply negative connotation) to describe why he felt a one-state solution would never work.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - "in all responsible accounts I've looked at" - clearly, they were not all that responsible. 99% of Palestinians who left **left on their own accord**, upon the urging of Arab states that attacked Israel (to be elsewhere during the war, and anticipating to return once Arabs squashed Israel). There were only 2 villages (out of entire Palestine) where Israelis actually deliberately drove people out in 1948. Oh, that's another point: if the Arab states didn't attack - urged on by samesaid Palestinians, mind you - Palestine would exist as a state since 1948.

Comment: @user4012: have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Palestine_war)

Comment: @MoziburUllah - I'm extremely familar with that material. It confirms exactly what my prior comment did. Only 2 places were cleaned out on purpose by Israel (Lydda and Ramle). The rest was 100% due to peple leaving voluntarily due to this: `Arab League refused to accept the UN partition plan, proclaimed the right of self-determination for the Arabs **across the whole of Palestine**, ... Over the next few days, contingents of 4 countries of the Arab League at that time, namely Egypt, Iraq, Transjordan, and Syria, invaded territory in the former British Mandate and fought the Israelis. ... `

Comment: @user4012: No, it doesn't.  The right of self determination for both the Arab & Jewish peoples was mentioned on the original Balfour declaration; interestingly, there was no mention of a Jewish State, but only of a Jewish National Home. Oh, and please spell people correctly, I can't take someone seriously who can't spell correctly.

Comment: ie "it being clearly understood that nothing shall be done which may prejudice the civil and religious rights of existing non-Jewish communities in Palestine".

Answer (score 1):

Most Jewish Israelis do not believe that they can live in freedom in a
state with too many Arabs. Right now, Israel is a Democratic state
with an Arab minority encompassing about 20%. Jewish Israelis believe
that if the Arab portion of the population grows too large, the state
will no longer be Jewish or Democratic.

The sentiment is well described in
[this essay](http://www.jpost.com/Opinion/Columnists/Essay-Could-an-Israeli-Arab-ever-be-elected-prime-minister-of-Israel) which was written shortly after Obama became President of the
United States:

> If, in a century, shifting demographics led Congress to become
>   predominantly African-American, or Asian, or Hispanic, that change
>   would simply be further indication of the flourishing of America's
>   vision, a sign that the scourge of racism had receded even
>   further. It would be testament to the realization of America's
>   purpose, not its demise. Not so, however, in Israel. For while
>   Israel must absolutely strive to make race a non-issue (even among
>   Jews, as with Ethiopians, for example) and to accord Israeli Arabs a
>   significantly greater piece of the pie, we ought to be honest: If
>   Israel one day were to have a Knesset in which a majority of the
>   members were Arab, Israel will have failed in its purpose.

In the US, a black man becoming president was considered a success for
racial equality. But in Israel, the prospect of an Arab assuming the
prime minister post is terrifying.

This answers your first question. Ehud Barak said "this bloc of
Palestinians cannot vote" because if "that bloc" of Palestinians were
allowed to vote in Israeli elections, the probability of an Arab being
elected prime minister would be much to high.

The second statement ties in with the first. He said "the state of
Israel is finished" not because he believe Israel would cease to
exist, but because he believes that if the state is not dominated by
Jews, it is worthless.

Barak and Olmert's statements are not unlike [Secretary of State John Kerry's](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/video/2016/12/28/kerry_israel_can_either_be_jewish_or_democratic_it_cannot_be_both.html) who said that Israeli can either be Jewish or Democratic:

- **Jewish**: Israel annexes the West Bank but does not grant Palestinians citizenship. The state continues to be Jewish but clearly becomes an undemocratic Apartheid state.
- **Democratic**: Israel annexes the West Bank and grants the Palestinians citizenship. The Palestinians can now vote and an Arab P.M. is probable. The state would then not be "Jewish."

The third solution, a (partial) withdrawal from the West Bank and
reaching a deal with the Palestinians, is what Kerry, Barak and
Olmert favors. It would save Israel's Jewish and Democratic
character. But for various reasons, the two-state solution is very
unlikely these days.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are not bad, but I'll try to concentrate on the asked questions, i.e. explaining the words of Ehud Barak and Ehud Olmert.

An underlying assumption in the words of both is that in a one state solution, The Palestinians of the west bank and Gaza won't be given equal rights. Many Israelis believe that equal rights to Palestinians will be used for anti-Jewish moves. For example, the right to vote could lead to an Arab majority passing anti-Jewish laws, and freedom of movement could be abused by terrorists. This assumption is somewhat supported by research quoted in [user4012's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/23129/14958).

Therefore, Olmert and Barak assume that this one state, or Greater Israel, will not give equal rights to the Palestinians of the west bank and Gaza. So in Barak's words, `this bloc of millions of Palestinians cannot vote` (unlike today, and in 2010, where all citizens can vote, including Arabs). This situation would not be democratic, and has significant similarty to South-African Apartheid.

Ehud Olmert goes further to claim that Israel will not be able to survive in such a situation, probably due to international isolation and sanctions. This view seems to be shared by some Palestinian organizations, that endeavor to equate Israel and Apartheid, in hope to reach isolation and sanctions.

Both Olmert and Barak use this argument to promote the two state solution, which they see as the only alternative to the above.